# Observing closeable resources to be closed when the subscriber is removed/disposed

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm working on a small subsystem that integrates two simple components using RxJava 2.
These two components work in a simple client-server manner where the first component produces observable data opening a resource under the hood.
The resource is not exposed to the second component.
Moreover, it must be open as long as the observable is in use, however the observable object cannot determine when it should be closed.
Speaking in code, an example implementation is like this:

```java
private Disposable disposable;

public void onCreate() {
    final Maybe<Object> maybeResource = Maybe.defer(() -> {
        System.out.println("open");
        // here is the resource under the hood, it is encapsulated in the observable and never gets exposed
        final Closeable resource = () -> { };
        return Maybe.just(resource)
                .doOnDispose(() -> {
                    // this "destructor" is never called, resulting in a resource leak
                    System.out.println("close");
                    resource.close();
                })
                // arbitrary data, does not represent the data I'm working with, but it hides the resource away
                .map(closeable -> new Object());
    });
    disposable = maybeResource.subscribe(data -> System.out.println("process: " + data));
}

public void onUserWorflow() {
    // ...
    System.out.println("... ... ...");
    // ...
}

public void onDestroy() {
    disposable.dispose();
}
```

The output I'd anticipate to get is:

```
open
process: <...>
... ... ...
close         <-- this is never produced
```

but the last line, `close`, is never produced as the `doOnDispose` method is not invoked and does not work as I might think it's supposed to.
Therefore the resource gets never released.
There is also `Maybe.using` that does a similar thing, but it does not allow to "span" across the "user workflow".

Is there an RxJava/RxJava 2 way that allows managing "closeable" resources closed on disposing a subscriber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you need to use `Observable.create()` instead of Maybe.
Something like that:

```
final Observable<Object> resourceObservable = Observable.create<Object> {(emitter ->
        // do you staff
        emitter.onNext(new Object()); //to make observable emit something
        emitter.setCancellable ( 
           System.out.println("close");
           resource.close(); 
        )
    );

disposable = resourceObservable.subscribe(data -> System.out.println("process: " + data));
```

Comment: Hm, that seems to be what I want at least for `Flowable`, thank you. Let me ask you: why does `Maybe` not behave like that? I mean, if I'm using `setCancellable` for the `MaybeEmitter`, the resource gets closed _before_ the "user workflow". Why? And one more please: should I use `setDisposable` instead of `setCancellable`?

Comment: Honestly: i'm not so familiar with `Maybe`, i've never used it (don't see any prompt of it, comparing to Flowable, Single, Observable). So not sure why it doesn't work for you. About  using `setDisposable`: according to docs it's almost the same, but you'll have to implement `Disposable` which has 2 methods instead of 1 in `Cancellable`.  So i use `setCancellable`

Comment: To my understanding, `Maybe` is a nullable `Single`, and I can see it makes pretty nice semantic sense. Perhaps the behavior differs because "maybies" can have a single value only, unlike "flowables", or I just faced a bug. Need to read the docs. Thank you!